# ZeroDivisionError pandas only when index is not datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas

I don't think giving MRE is not necessary so I will just go right to it.

I have a dataframe where index is datetimeindex, when I do `df.apply(lambda row:row.x/row.y, axis=1)`, even though some rows of y column has value of 0 it works.

I am curious why it gives `ZeroDivisionError` when I reset_index and run `df.apply(lambda row:row.x/row.y, axis=1)` therefore index is not datetimeindex. What is the reason, even though I am not using index in my calculations?

using df.x/df.y does not output `ZeroDivisonError` as well.

Comment: just an fyi, `df.x/df.y` would work better.

Comment: lol true, I don't know why I used apply. Thanks